# Is there a lazy Session IO Monad?

Tags: haskell

You have a sequence of actions that prefer to be executed in chunks due to some high-fixed overhead like packet headers or making connections. The limit is that sometimes the next action depends on the result of a previous one in which case, all pending actions are executed at once.

Example:

```
mySession :: Session IO ()
    a <- readit  -- nothing happens yet
    b <- readit  -- nothing happens yet
    c <- readit  -- nothing happens yet
    if a       -- all three readits execute because we need a
      then write "a"
      else write "..."
    if b || c  -- b and c already available
      ...
```

This reminds me of so many Haskell concepts but I can't put my finger on it.

Of course, you could do something obvious like:

```
[a,b,c] <- batch([readit, readit, readit])
```

But I'd like to hide the fact of chunking from the user for slickness purposes.

Not sure if Session is the right word. Maybe you can suggest a better one? (Packet, Batch, Chunk and Deferred come to mind.)

### Update

I think there was a really good answer last night that I read on my phone but when I came back to look for it today it was gone. Was I dreaming?

Comment: You are describing `unsafeInterleaveIO`. Stay away from it, it's evil. You will get IO actions being run inside pure code. Changing `a+b` into `b+a` may break your program since IO actions are running in the opposite order. Don't say I didn't warn you. :-P

Comment: @chi hmm, the idea is to force the whole block (a, b, and c) when any of the values are forced. That doesn't change ordering.

Comment: `unsafeInterleaveIO` is nowhere near as evil as `unsafePerformIO`, but can still introduce bugs if you're not careful with it. For example: if you're using it to load something into a list, you have to think about whether iterating over the list itself will trigger the IO actions or whether it will be triggered by evaluating the actual elements.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do exactly what you want, since what you describe exploits haskell's lazy evaluation to have the evaluation of `a` force the actions that compute `b` and `c`, and there's no way to `seq` on unspecified values.

What I could do was hack together a monad transformer that delayed actions sequenced via `>>` so that they could be executed all together:

```
data Session m a = Session { pending :: [ m () ], final :: m a }                    

runSession :: Monad m => Session m a -> m a                                         
runSession (Session ms ma) = foldr (flip (>>)) (return ()) ms >> ma                            

instance Monad m => Monad (Session m) where                                         
  return = Session [] . return                                                      
  s >>= f = Session [] $ runSession s >>= (runSession . f)                          
  (Session ms ma) >> (Session ms' ma') =
    Session (ms' ++ (ma >> return ()) : ms) ma'
```

This violates some [monad laws,](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws) but lets you do something like:

```
 liftIO :: IO a -> Session IO a  
 liftIO = Session []             

 exampleSession :: Session IO Int
 exampleSession = do             
   liftIO $ putStrLn "one"       
   liftIO $ putStrLn "two"       
   liftIO $ putStrLn "three"     
   liftIO $ putStrLn "four"      
   trace "five" $ return 5
```

and get

```
ghci> runSession exampleSession
five
one
two
three
four
5
ghci> length (pending exampleSession)
4
```

Comment: This is interesting. Why does it violate some monad laws? It seems like it will execute in the same order as IO would. Okay, I try putting a `l <- liftIO getLine` in the middle of the sequence after "two".) and now "five" prints after the getLine instead of first thing. That does seem troubling.

Comment: You can make it not violate the monad laws by making the definition for `(>>=)` similar to that of `(>>)`. The definition for `(>>)` can then be excluded.

Comment: is7s: it's not obvious to me what that definition of `(>>=)` would be.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to what [Haxl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxl) does.

For more info:

- [Open sourcing haxl - Facebook Code Blog](https://code.facebook.com/posts/302060973291128/open-sourcing-haxl-a-library-for-haskell/)
- [ICFP 2014 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG9PWdV1wso)

Comment: Unfortunately the issue here is different IMO. Haxl is applicative (so successive steps don't depends on result of previous steps), while here there is data dependency.

Comment: @Yuras Looks like there's a [Haxl Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxl-0.1.0.0/docs/Haxl-Core-Monad.html). Is it the Monad I'm searching for? Hard to say. Still reading the haddock.

Comment: @MichaelFox I'm not sure now, because I probably misunderstood the question. I'll try to come later with stronger claims.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `unsafeInterleaveIO` function. It is a dangerous function that can introduce bugs to your program if not used carefully, but it does what you're asking for.

You can insert it into your example code like this:

```
lazyReadits :: IO [a]
lazyReadits = unsafeInterleaveIO $ do
  a <- readit
  r <- lazyReadits
  return (a:r)
```

`unsafeInterleaveIO` makes the action as a whole lazy, but once it starts evaluating it will evaluate as if it had been strict. This means in my above example: `readit` will run as soon as something tests whether the returned list is empty or not. If I'd used `mapM unsafeInterleaveIO (replicate 3 readit)` instead, then `readit` would only be run when the actual elements of the list are evaluated, which would make the contents of the list depend on the order in which its elements are inspected, which is one example of how `unsafeInterleaveIO` can introduce bugs.